# Are objects from For Loops passed by reference or value?

Tags: update, loop, reference

If I have a for loop that loops through results from a database query, is the single record a reference or copied value?

The reason I ask is because I am attempting to update these records, but would it be better to update the whole array, or each one individually?

For example, which option is the better way to update multiple objects:

```
// Option 1
for (Object__c obj: objects) {
    obj.name = "new_name";
    update obj;
}

// Option 2 (possibility depending if "obj" is referenced or not)
for (Object__c obj: objects) {
    obj.name = "new_name";
}
update objects;

// Option 3 (same as Option 2, but different access method)
for (Integer i = 0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
    objects[I] = "new_name";
}
update objects;
```

I guess, basically what I'm asking is if Option 2 and Option 3 do the same thing? Or is the better practice option 1?

Comment: @Himanshu just a friendly reminder, comments are for clarification of the question, not answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference.

Option 1 is Bad because it is un-bulkified. That pattern will rapidly chew through your slim allotment of 150 DML statements per transaction, yielding a `LimitException`.

Options 2 and 3 are largely equivalent, with 2 being more idiomatic. The integer loop variable is extraneous *unless* you have some other need to have access to the loop index.

Both 2 and 3 are effectively bulkified, meaning your code will be more performant, all else being equal, and will have much lower limits risk. It's important to note that limits still *apply* to bulkified code, but you'll be consuming them at a much more sustainable rate. You'll use only one DML statement in these options, although you'll still use N DML rows for N records - but the row limit is 10,000, rather than 150!

(Option 3 is missing the `.Name`, but I don't think that's material to your example).

Comment: Technically Objects are passed "by reference by value" and not "by reference". https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/05/passing-parameters-by-reference-and-by-value-in-apex.html#:~:text=The%20current%20Apex%20documentation%20says,speaking%2C%20this%20is%20not%20true.

Answer (score 2):

We can only do 150 DML statements in 1 transaction. If you are trying to insert 1000 records using option 1, The code will break with LIMITS Exception. Check DML [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) . Doing DML and SOQL in for loops is RED FLAG. Very bad in SF environment.

Option 2 and 3 are better than option 1.

Performance wise option 2 will be better as you are not manually accessing array via Index and letting salesforce do that job for you.